# Custom Filter in cPanel to Auto-Delete Emails with Russian Characters

Tags: spam, encoding, filtering

I get a lot of spam to my email account from Russia. The emails themselves (name, subject, body) are in Russian and I was hoping to create a custom filter in cPanel (not in SpamAssassin but in cPanel itself) to catch these emails and delete them before they hit my inbox. I've tried setting up rules to flag emails with these characters but they still are getting through. This leads me to believe that there is an encoding issue at play here. Unfortunately I do not know how to overcome this. Ideas?

I already have Spamassassin configured to delete emails with a .ru TLD. These emails have other TLDs like .com, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s/a has a setting for languages,  there is usually comments in the s/a folder - user prefs file, add this

ok_locales en          (only allow English)

see-
http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html

(user prefs)

will/dallas

Comment: Being on a shared server I don't think I can change this but it's good to know. Thanks.